# Is there a solution for $xy=a, xy=b$?

Tags: calculus

As per title.

I have a system of equations where:
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}Axy = B\\
Cxy = D
\end{aligned}\right.$$

$A,B,C,D$ are constants. Is there a solution to this equation?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't say more that $b/a = d / c$ or $b c = ad$.

Comment: Well, $Axy = B \Rightarrow xy = \frac{B}{A}$, and from the other equation you get $xy= \frac{D}{C}$. Therefore $\frac{B}{A} = \frac{D}{C}$

Comment: The question significantly differs from the title.

Comment: @Yves is the difference that significant if you could rearrange the equations? In particular, given that $A, B, C, D$ are all constants, it shouldn't affect the solution, right?

Comment: @Lawrence: wrong. There are more cases to consider.

Comment: @yves what kind of cases should I be considering?

Comment: @Lawrence: zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the constants.
From $Axy=B$ you get two possibilities. 
1. if $A \neq 0 \Rightarrow xy = \frac{B}{A} $.
Then, if $x \neq 0 \Rightarrow y = \frac{B}{Ax} $.
Putting this into the second education gives you $Cx \frac{B}{Ax} = D $, so $ C \frac{B}{A} = D $.
 If it is true, that $CB=AD$ then any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y= \frac{B}{Ax} $ solve the system.
Else, if $x=0$, the solution is $x=0, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

2. And if $A = 0 \Rightarrow B=0$. So you basically have only one equation. If also $C$ or $D$ is equal to $0$, than any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ are good.
   In other case the best you can do, is say $y = \frac{D}{Cx} $, if $x \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. $A=B=C=D=x=y=0$ is a solution to your system two equations.

In fact, $A=B=C=D=0$ is a solution to your system no matter what the values of $x$ and $y$ are.

Answer (score 0):

I will discuss the problem $xy=a=b$.

Obviously you need $a=b$ for a solution to exist.

Then if $a=0$, $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$ are solutions for all $x,y$.

Else,

$$\left(t,\frac at\right)$$ for all $t\ne0$.